# Power supply voltage divider incorrect output voltage

Tags: power-supply, resistors, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider, high-voltage

I am currently working on a high voltage (up to **HVP-HVN** = 2.5KV) power supply. I am having some huge issues in my actual output voltage vs expected output voltage of a voltage divider in my power supply circuit. The output voltage when measured is much higher than the expected value, almost like R28 and R29 become smaller when voltage is applied. I will list some measurements out along with their expected values. **Vout_real is measured at the node between R29 and R30, in reference to HVN.**

**HVP-HVN:** 223.5 V, **Vout_Expected** = .135 V, **Vout_real** = 6.4v.
**HVP-HVN:** 375 V, **Vout_Expected** = .227 V, **Vout_real** = 10.2v.
**HVP-HVN:** 534.5 V, **Vout_Expected** = .323 V, **Vout_real** = 11.6v.

The discrepancies between expected and measured values are way big and I am having a hard time figuring out what is going on. I have tried switching out all the resistors of the voltage divider multiple time, including changing the resistor values(still with the same ratio). As well, I have also switched out the components connected to the voltage divider output. The output of the voltage divider connects to a voltage follower and an opto-isolator. Whether there is a load connected across the HVP and HVN terminals, the voltage divider still acts the same way. Any thoughts or recommendations? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are R28 & R29 rated for high voltage operation? What sort of flux are you using? Water soluble fluxes become conductive and create havoc around high impedance circuits as you have with R28 & R29. Which segues in to how clean the board surface is around R28 & R29.

Comment: How & where are you measuring Vout_real?

Comment: The resistors are rated for high voltages. As for the flux, I’m not sure, I’d have to double check. 

Vout_real is being measured at the node between r29 and r30 in reference to HVN.

Comment: Where is Vout_real measured at? Are the buffer and isolator (datasheet: https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-4715EN ) working correctly? Showing the layout may also prove illuminating.

Comment: Vout_real is measured at the node between R29 and R30 in reference to HVN. I added a picture of the pcb layout above. The isolator is acting as it should. The buffer does not act as I would expect, but it acts the same when I replace it even. Maybe I got a bad batch of ad712's.